# decode compose in console application

Tags: ios, swift, console-application

I using OS Logger API for logging (see logs in console.app)
when printing message on which contains precent
Like this
`json=%7B%22name%22%3A%22search%22%2C%22section%22%3A%22index%22%7D%22` 
(Run code on iOS simulator) in console app prints
`json=7B<decode: can't compose [%22n]>`
But when run code on MacOS it works fine

My code

```
let logger = os.Logger(subsystem: "subsystem", category: "category")
logger.log(level: .debug, "\(message, privacy: .public)")
```

Expect full message in console app

also find workaround `"\(message)".replacingOccurrences(of: "%", with: "%%")` but I would not like to do that